# Period of 3 implies chaos

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Let's denote $k$-times repeated application of the function, $f(f(f(...f(x)...)))$ as $f^{(k)}(x)$.

Let's call any $x$ a **periodic point** with period $n$ if $f^{(n)}(x)=x$.

Is it true that if a point with period 3 exists, then points with all possible periods exist?

In other words is it true that

$$\exists x:f^{(3)}(x)=x\Rightarrow \forall n>0 \exists y:f^{(n)}(y)=y$$

and if so, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [Chaos: An Introduction to Dynamical Systems](http://books.google.com/books?id=48YHnbHGZAgC&dq=chaos+an+introduction+to+dynamical+systems&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=wVtvTLaRE4nAsAPVt52uCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kathleen T. Alligood, Tim D. Sauer, and James A. Yorke, to be a sensible text.  A small section of the text contains a brief explanation of Sharkovsky's Theorem.

In short, Sharkovsky uses this unique ordering of the natural numbers in such a way as to ensure that for each natural number n, the existence of a period-n point implies the existence of periods containing all the periods of orders higher than n. In my opinion, the text provides a reasonable simplification of this ordering and gently walks one through a decipherable step by step proof.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you want [Sharkovsky's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SharkovskysTheorem.html).

A reasonable explanation is in:

Kaplan, Harvey. "A cartoon-assisted proof of Sarkowskiĭ's theorem."
Amer. J. Phys. 55 (1987), no. 11, 1023–1032.
MR[917121](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=917121)
DOI:[10.1119/1.14928"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.14928)

Comment: Thanks... do you have the proof as well?

Comment: I linked a fairly good explanation in an article.  It looks like this is covered in a lot of "dynamics" or "chaos" textbooks too, so you might just check the library for a readable one.  I get the feeling that Harvey Kaplan felt most of the explanations were too scary, and so wrote this reasonable one.  It's been 23 years, so I would assume the textbooks are better now.

Answer (score 9):

See the Monthly paper of that exact title [Period three implies chaos](http://pb.math.univ.gda.pl/chaos/pdf/li-yorke.pdf) - which made the JSTOR [All-Stars](http://www.maa.org/news/062607jstor.html) list as the third most frequently accessed Monthly article. See also [A simple proof of Sharkovsky's theorem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4145161) and this [paper](http://links.jstor.org/sici?sici=0002-9890%28199711%29104%3A9%3C846%3AROST%3E2.0.CO%3B2-G) for some history on Sharkovsky's theorem.

Answer (score 7):

This is (a special case of) a famous theorem, and of course there are many published proofs. However, knowing the statement, you might be able to work out a proof yourself.

The simple key fact for the proof is:

*Lemma.* Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on the compact interval $I=[a,b]$ such that the image of $f$ contains $I$. Then $f$ has a fixed point.

(Hint: intermediate value theorem.)

Now suppose you have a period 3 orbit. First of all think about how the three points $x_1<x_2<x_3$ of the orbit can be permuted by the function - you will notice that you can assume without loss of generality that $f(x_1)=x_2$, $f(x_2)=x_3$ and $f(x_3)=x_1$. Consider the two intervals $I_1=[x_1,x_2]$ and $I_2=[x_2,x_3]$. What do we know about the image of these intervals under $f$? Already you should see that $f$ must have a fixed point. With a little bit more work, you can see that $f$ has periodic points of every period $n$. (Show that there is a subinterval $J$ of $I_2$ such that $f^{n-1}(J)= I_1$ and $f^j(J)\subset I_2$ for $1\leq j<n-1$.)